# AutofacContrib: Should I download assemblies or use source code directly?

Tags: autofac

I need to use a few AutofacContrib projects. I think I have 2 options:

1) Download the zip package from the official download page, then copy the assemblies to my projects.

2) Copy the source code from the official repository to my projects (Common project shared by all solutions).

It seems to me, that copy source code to my Common project is most convenient (the AutofacContrib projects that I needed contain only 9 class files, I can simply copy the source code from web browser). But I'm not sure if it's a good practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G'day there- I'd recommend just grabbing the source code if it is something small. Contrib opens up opportunities to experiment: if you make improvements you might even be able to post them back to the project :)